# No HDMI sound in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sound, hdmi

I made a fresh install of Ubuntu 13.10 on my desktop. I have a problem with the sound.

As you can see from the screenshot, Ubuntu detected my "HDMI sound card" that is onboard the Gigabyte GA-MA78G-DS3H motherboard. It appears on card 1. I do not see it on "Play Sound Through" (screenshot), and thus, cannot select it as the output for audio.

I connected my computer to the TV via an HDMI cable, and the video is fine, but there is no sound.

How can I get Ubuntu to install my HDMI sound card on "Play Sound Through", so I can select it and get sound out?

Dear Wilf. I'm new to AskUbuntu, so here is a link to the screenshots. Hope you can see them. I have an integrated ATI Radeon HD 3200 graphics card on moatherboard.
Georg
https://plus.google.com/photos/102984125071432149914/albums/5983280717706993697

Hello Terminal. I installed the "Pulse Audio Volume Control", but it did not help. I still do not get sound from my HDMI. George

Comment: Upload the image using http://imgur.com - then we will be able to see the screenshots - we don;t all have access to the Pictures directory in your home directory :-) - Please also add what graphics you are using - you can use `lspci -v`, or `lshw -C display`.

Comment: Dear Wilf. I'm new to AskUbuntu, so here is a link to the screenshots. Hope you can see them. I have an integrated ATI Radeon HD 3200 graphics card on moatherboard. Georg https://plus.google.com/photos/102984125071432149914/albums/5983280717706993697

Comment: It appears under `aplay -l`, so it might not be a drivers issue...

Answer (score -1):

Installing Pulse Audio Volume Control ,gives the HDMI audio options, needed: From:https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/paman/

hope this helps!

Comment: Hello Terminal. I installed the "Pulse Audio Volume Control", but it did not help. I still do not get sound from my HDMI. George

Comment: You can also try [`pavucontrol`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/) - [image here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NSe7R.png)